# Auto-wiring for Ninject

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject

Some of the IOC containers have what's called auto-wiring based on conventions, for e.g., IProductRepository maps to ProductRepository without any manual wiring on your part.

Is there such a thing with Ninject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// use Ninject.Extensions.Conventions for convention-based binding
kernel.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        // look for types in this assembly
        scanner.FromCallingAssembly();

        // make ISomeType bind to SomeType by default (remove the 'I'!)
        scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
    });
```

copied from @Pete Montgomery comment

Answer (score 7):

Ninject comes with an extension for convention based configuration. But you still need to configure your convenions. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions The syntax has changed for 3.0.0 but has become much more powerful. The following would add bindings for all classes in your system. But normally you want several of these conventions for different kind of classes (e.g. services are singletons, ....)

```
kernel.Bind(
    x => x.FromThisAssembly()
          .SelectAllClasses()
          .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Comment: Works, but last line shoud read .BindAllInterfaces() by 3.0.2